# MySQL Working out number of orders by customer in the previous year

Tags: mysql, sql

Wondering how to get something like this done in MySQL - basically I need to get the number of orders in the previous year by order, so if someone made three orders (1.1.13, 1.7.13 and 1.1.15 the first and last orders would be zero as there were no bookings in the previous year but the middle one would be one as there was a booking 6 months before).

Something like this gets the first three, not sure how to get the total?

```
SELECT order_no, email, order_date
FROM table.orders

order_no    email                       order_date      prev_yr_orders

143254      example@example.com 25/07/2013           1

646743      example@example.com 24/09/2013           2

757743      example@example.com 16/02/2014           3

993253      example@example.com 23/02/2014           4

535325      example@example.com 31/03/2015           1
```

Comment: Not clear what you are asking. Your example does not figure in the code example. What do you want to achieve?

Answer (score 0):

You can do this easily using a correlated subquery:

```
select o.*,
       (select count(*)
        from orders o2
        where o2.email = o.email and
              o2.order_date < o.order_date and
              o2.order_date >= o.order_date - interval 1 year
       ) as NumOrdersPrevYear
from orders o;
```